# Can you show why is a dihedral group homomorphic to a symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

My professor mentioned something about function composition. But to show homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$, we need $f(x*y) = f(x)*f(y)$, for $x,y$ in $G$. How can you show this exactly in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Math S. E.  Elements of a dihedral group are some permutations of vertices of an $n$-gon

Comment: Well, **every** group is homomorphic to $S_1$, so that's kind of trivial. I believe the dihedral group is also homomorphic to $S_2$. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only $D_3\cong S_3$.

In general, all you can say is that a dihedral group is embeddable as a *subgroup* of some $S_n$.  But, any group embeds into a symmetric group, by Cayley's theorem.

You may be thinking, rather, of the theorem that dihedral groups are symmetries of regular $n$-gons.

Comment: OP asked for homomorphism, not isomorphism

Comment: There's no such thing as "homomorphic groups", as far as I'm concerned.  I guess I shouldn't have answered. @J.W. Tanner

Answer (score 0):

The dihedral group of order  $2n$ permutes the vertices of a regular $n$-gon. Permutations form the elements of each symmetric group.

Comment: It seems to me that this proves that there's a map between the two groups, but not yet that is a homomorphism, isn't It?